# How to call ambiguous generic function in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift, ambiguity

I've defined two generic functions

```
func job<T: Comparable>(x: T) {
  println("1")
}

func job<T: Hashable>(x: T) {
  println("2")
}
```

and when I try to call one of them, for example with:

```
let myInt: Int = 1 // Explicit Int just for clarity of the example
job(myInt)
```

of course Swift complains and throws an error
**Ambiguous use of 'job'**
which is understandable, because it is not clear whether I want to use the **Comparable** one or **Hashable** (**Int** conforms to both of them)

Is there a way I can hint the compiler which one I want to use?

Comment: Does `job(myInt as Hashable)` work?

Comment: Nope :( I get 2 errors:
`Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or assosiated type requirements`  
AND `Type 'Hashable' does not conform to protocol 'Comparable'` (this one sounds weird :) )

Comment: FYI for the latest swift note these two great answers ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39836054/294884 ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39835658/294884

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ambiguous because `Int` is both `Hashable` and `Comparable`, and neither of those two protocols are in the same hierarchy. (You can view the `Int` [protocol hierarchy on Swifter](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Int/hierarchy/).)

```
func f<T: Hashable>(t: T) {
    println("Hashable: \(t)")
}
func f<T: Comparable>(t: T) {
    println("Comparable: \(t)")
}

let number = 5
f(number)
// error: ambiguous use of 'f'
```

You can't explicitly tell it which function to call, because of the associated type requirements of each protocol, but what you *can* do is define a third function:

```
func f<T: Comparable where T: Hashable>(t: T) {
    println("Both Hashable & Comparable: \(t)")
}
f(number)
// Both Hashable & Comparable: 5
```

This is how [Swift implements](http://swifter.natecook.com/operator/dotdotlt/) the `..<` operator, which otherwise would be ambiguous for types that implement both `Comparable` and `ForwardIndexType`.

---

To expand a little further, here's a look at what I meant by "you can't explicitly tell it which function to call, because of the associated type requirements of each protocol." Protocols can be used as types, as described in the Swift book [chapter on Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_400):

```
protocol RandomNumberGenerator {
    func random() -> Double
}

class Dice {
    let generator: RandomNumberGenerator
    // ...
}
```

In this example, the generator property can be any type that conforms to `RandomNumberGenerator` - similar to how `id<ProtocolName>` is used in Objective-C. However, protocols can *only* be used as types when they do not include an associated type or reference `Self` in their declaration. This unfortunately excludes nearly every built-in type in Swift, including `Hashable` and `Comparable`.

`Hashable` inherits from `Equatable`, which references `Self` when defining the `==` operator:

```
func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

and `Comparable` does the same with its operators:

```
func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
// similar definitions for <, >, and >=
```

These protocols can *only* be used as generic constraints, and not used as a type when declaring a variable. (As far as I can tell this is undocumented, but discoverable through error messages.)

Two protocols that *don't* have that restriction are `Printable` and `BooleanType`, so we can look at how they work. `Bool` is the only built-in type that conforms to `BooleanType`, and it is also `Printable`, so that will be our test type. Here are our generic functions `p()` and the variable `t` - note that, as before, we can't just call the function with `t`:

```
func p<T: Printable>(t: T) {
    println("Printable: \(t)")
}
func p<T: BooleanType>(t: T) {
    println("BooleanType: \(t)")
}

let t: Bool = true
p(t)
// error: Ambiguous use of 'p'
```

Instead, we need to cast (upcast?) `t` to a particular protocol using the `as` keyword, and call a particular generic function that way:

```
p(t as Printable)
// Printable: true

p(t as BooleanType)
// BooleanType: true
```

So as long as we have a qualifying protocol, we can choose which variant of the generic method to call.

Comment: To clarify, `Comparable` and `Hashable` methods were just to demonstrate the problem. I do not expect to need them, but I wanted to understand how limited I may be in the future. Now, I'm not sure what you mean by "You can't explicitly tell it which function to call, **because of the associated type requirements of each protocol**". Is there some fundamental issue here with being able to provide the compiler with a hint about which method to use? Do you think we can expect such a feature in the future?

Comment: Isn't telling the compiler which function to use kind of in opposition to the design of generic programming (in general, not just in Swift)? Regardless, if there's a feature you want to see (or at least be told not to expect) in the future, it's probably best to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: @BartekChlebek: Added a little (okay, a lot) of explanation on that point. Swift is certainly in flux, but I don't necessarily see that it needs to change. This kind of conflict seems relatively rare, no?

Comment: @NateCook wow, I appreciate your answer, now it's clear. While I agree that such conflicts should be incredibly rare, I still think that it's a limitation that could be resolved in the future versions of Swift. Your example with `Printable` and `BooleanType` demonstrates that some of such functionality already exists.