# Swift 3 needs more info, to infer a parameter?

Tags: generics, swift3

I have an extension which bubbles upwards,

but in Swift 3,

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

```
public extension UIResponder
    {
    public func next<T>() -> T?
        {
        guard let responder = self.next
            else { return nil }
        return (responder as? T) ?? responder.next()
        }
    }

 // note - kudos to this excellent post:
 // https://blog.veloxdb.com/2016/05/12/bubbling-events-using-uiresponder-in-swift/
```

in Swift<3, you could use that like this:

```
class SnapDot:UIView 
    {
    .....
    func handleTap(g:UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
        (next() as Snap?)?.oneDotWasClicked(self)
        }
```

I'm afraid that not only (a) I can't see why it wouldn't be inferred in Swift 3, but (b) even by endlessly trying random variations, I can't get it to work in Swift 3  :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a name collision between the existing `next` method of `UIResponder`, and your extension method. `self.next` inside
your method refers to the (generic) method itself.

Renaming the extension makes it compile:

```
public extension UIResponder {
    public func nextOfType<T>() -> T? {
        guard let responder = self.next
            else { return nil }
        return (responder as? T) ?? responder.nextOfType()
    }
}
```

And even if you didn't ask for it, here is an iterative instead of
recursive version :)

```
public extension UIResponder {
    public func nextOfType<T>() -> T? {
        var current = self
        while let responder = current.next {
            if let match = responder as? T {
                return match
            }
            current = responder
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: What's *really* weird is that adding a unnamed argument to the function works, e.g `public func next<T>(_: Void = ()) -> T?`. It seems that the compiler isn't able to disambiguate between properties and argument-less methods with the same names (I don't see why you shouldn't be able to disambiguate by casting or by type inference in this case)

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, declaring both a computed property `var foo` and a method `func foo() -> Int` fails with "invalid redeclaration" in both Swift 2 and 3.

Comment: I must admit, apropos my OTHER tricky extension, which you guys had to fix ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835397  ... I'm confused why I don't need to use the metatype here.  (Or indeed could this be written using a metatype approach? as opposed to the `if let` ?)

Comment: @JoeBlow: You can either pass the (meta) type as an parameter (as in your other question) or let it infer from the context (as in this question). I don't think that one approach is better than the other, do whatever you understand best.